# How to start apache2 in command line specifying a port?

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp

I would like to start Apache2 server in my Linux command line specifying a port.
A solution which don't need to edit php.ini would be nice, because the command should not request sudo.

I need to access to the server with this adress:

```
http://localhost:1234/
```

For the moment, it start at:

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? the later versions can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5.4 you can run a localhost server from the command line using

```
php -S localhost:1234
```

PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

You may need to add php to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem.
I didn't knew I can do that with php command.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.